# Perl Regex get last digits in string before \

Tags: regex, perl

Do you know of a way to combine these 2 regular expressions?
Or any other way to just get the last 6 digits before the last `\`.

The end result that I want is `100144` from the string:

> `\\XXX\Extract_ReduceSize\MonitoringExport\dev\files\100144\`

Here are some things I have tried

```
(.{1})$
```

Gets rid of the trailing `\` of the string resulting in

> `\\XXX\Extract_ReduceSize\MonitoringExport\dev\files\100144`

```
.*\\
```

Gets rid of everything before the last `\` resulting in `100144`

The software I am using requires just one line. So I can perform 2 calls.

Comment: *"The software I am using"*: what software?

Comment: `m|.*/(.*)/$|`.  But if these are file paths there are other ways

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the last one, would `([^\\]*)\\$` be appropriate? This matches with as many non-slash characters as possible before the last slash. Alternatively, if you don't want to extract the first group, you can do a lookahead with `([^\\]+)(?=\\$)`.

Answer (score 1):

This code shows two different solutions. Hope it helps:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $example = '\\XXX\Extract_ReduceSize\MonitoringExport\dev\files\100144\\';

# Method 1: split the string by the \ character. This gives us an array, 
# and then, select the last element of that array [-1]
my $number = (split /\\/, $example)[-1];
print $number, "\n"; # <-- prints: 100144

# Method 2: use a regexpr. Search in reverse mode ($), 
# and catch the number part (\d+) in $1
if( $example =~ m!(\d+)\\$! ) {
    print $1, "\n"; # <-- prints: 100144
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works to extract the last segment of digits:

```
(\d+)(?=\\$)
```